# '>' not supported between instances of 'property' and 'int'

Tags: python, spyder

I have the codes below:

```
class TransactedProperty:

    def __init__(self, address, propertyValue):
        self._address = address
        self._propertyValue = propertyValue

    @property
    def address(self):
        return self._address
    @property
    def propertyValue(self):
        return self._propertyValue
    @propertyValue.setter
    def propertyValue(self, newpropertyValue):
        self._propertyValue = newpropertyValue

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Property Address: {self._address} Value: ${self._propertyValue}'
```

I tried to pass propertyValue into another class.

```
class Transaction:
    _nextTransactionId = 1
    def __init__(self, transactionId, TransactedProperty, Buyer):
        self._transactionId = transactionId
        self._TransactedProperty = TransactedProperty
        self._Buyer = Buyer
        # self._ABSDRate = Buyer.getABSDRate
        # self._ABSDRate = ABSDRate
        Transaction._nextTransactionId += 1

    #ItemDelivery()
    @property
    def Buyer(self):
        return self._Buyer
    @property
    def TransactedProperty(self):
        return self._TransactedProperty
```

Then do comparison:

```
    def BSDPayable(self):
        newPropertyValue = 0
        toAdd =  0
        propertyValue = TransactedProperty.propertyValue
        while True:
            if propertyValue> 180000:
                toAdd = 180000 * 0.1
                newPropertyValue = propertyValue - 180000
                if newPropertyValue > 180000:
                    toAdd2 = 180000 * 0.2
                    BDS = toAdd + toAdd2
                    newPropertyValue = newPropertyValue - 180000
                    if newPropertyValue > 640000:
                        toAdd3 = 640000 * 0.3
                        BDS = toAdd + toAdd2 + toAdd3
                        newPropertyValue = newPropertyValue - 640000
                        if newPropertyValue > 0:
                            toAdd4 = newPropertyValue * 0.4
                            BDS = toAdd + toAdd2 + toAdd3 + toAdd4
                        else:
                            break
                    return BDS
```

Then call by:

I passed in the propertyvalue 345678885 under class TransactedProperty, so it should pass over when it is called for calculations.

```
def main():
        p1 = TransactedProperty('Oxley Road', 345678885)
```

The error code:
'>' not supported between instances of 'property' and 'int'
keeps appearing, any advice?

Comment: You have a very poor choice of variables names, for example: `def __init__(self, transactionId, TransactedProperty, Buyer):` you call a variable with the name of a class you've already declared. See [Pep 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) to correct that and edit your answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

With your actual code you're trying to compare a property object:

```py
propertyValue = TransactedProperty.propertyValue
propertyValue
>>> <property object at 0x7f190c1db410>
```

You need to initialize properly:

```py
propertyValue = TransactedProperty("id", 123456)
propertyValue.propertyValue
>>> 123456
```

Comment: Thank you, i've tried before and it doesn't work.
Error code: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'property'.

Comment: My apologies, i'm still not sure where I should modify my codes. Could you please advice further?
I'll put what I did below.

Comment: `    def BSDPayable(self):
        newPropertyValue = 0
        toAdd =  0
        propertyValue = TransactedProperty(TransactedProperty.address, TransactedProperty.propertyValue)
        
        while True:
            if propertyValue.propertyValue > 180000:
                toAdd = 180000 * 0.1`

Comment: Edit your question accordingly